# What's wrong with the syntax of this batch script?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, putty, batch-file

I'm trying to autoload Putty Pageant with some SSH-keys with a batch script, but because I want to bypass the error message of Pageant that it is already running, I placed it in an IF-statement. For some reason however, it doesn't work:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq pageant.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "pageant.exe">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 ( :: checks whether pageant.exe is running or not

    :: set the SSH-keys
    if exist "C:\SSH keys\key1.ppk" (set KEYS="C:\SSH keys\key1.ppk")
    if exist "C:\SSH keys\key2.ppk" (set KEYS=%KEYS% "C:\SSH keys\key2.ppk")

    if not defined KEYS (
        msg * A SSH-key is propably missing.
    )

    :: Start pageant with the defined SSH-keys
    start /d"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" pageant.exe %KEYS%

)
```

While they do work separately:
(1)

```
 tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq pageant.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "pageant.exe">NUL
 if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 ( :: checks whether pageant.exe is running or not

       :: This works!
       start /d"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" pageant.exe

 )
```

(2)

```
:: set the SSH-keys
if exist "C:\SSH keys\key1.ppk" (set KEYS="C:\SSH keys\key1.ppk")
if exist "C:\SSH keys\key2.ppk" (set KEYS=%KEYS% "C:\SSH keys\key2.ppk")

if not defined KEYS (
    msg * A SSH-key is propably missing.
)

This works as well!
start /d"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" pageant.exe %KEYS%
```

Is it a syntax problem?

Comment: A job for Stackoverflow?

Comment: @GuyThomas Stack Overflow isn't particularly happy about questions that just consist of code and a request to fix it. The OP should explain what exactly fails instead of saying that "it doesn't work", and show what they've narrowed the problem down to. Batch scripting questions are on topic here and don't need to be migrated away, especially when it comes down to scripting for software that doesn't even have to do with programming (e,g. PuTTy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an error message I can only guess.

**Do you have delayed expansion enabled?  See [`setlocal /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772046%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).**

Add this to the beggining of your script
`setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`
and
`endlocal` to the end of your script.

This allows the `KEYS` variable to evaluate the the actual value.  Delayed expansion allows the value to be set immediately to the variable not just when the scope of the `if` statement has ended. Also don't forget to use `!` instead of `%` for the variables set inside the if statement.

**Example:** (Run this in a `.bat` once with the `EnableDepayedExpansion` and once without and you will see the difference.)

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Value=Hello World"
echo %Value%
if 1==1 (
    set "Value=Goodbye World"
    echo %Value%
    echo !Value!
)
echo %Value%

endlocal
```

Comment: That sounds promising. I will try that tomorrow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fantastic! That works. It is indeed the combination between EnableDepayedExpansion and the exclamation marks that did the trick.